# How to model data in NoSQL Firebase datastore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I want to store following data:

Users,
Events,
Attendees

*(similar to Firebase's example given here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ran_Ylug7AE)*

---

My Firebase store is like the following:

Users - Collection

```
    {
       "9582940055" : 
                       {
                         "name" : "test"
                       }
    }
```

Every user is a different document. Am I doing it correctly?

If yes, I have kept Mobile number of every user as `Document Id` instead of `auto id`, as the mobile number is going to be unique and it will help me in querying. Is this right?

---

Events - Collection

```
    {
       "MkyzuARd8Uelh0qD1WMa" : // auto id for every event
                       {
                         "name" : "test",                           
                         "attendees" : {
                                      "user": 'Lakshay'
                                       }
                       }
    }
```

Here, I have kept attendees as a `Map` inside the Event document. Is it right or should I make Attendees as a collection inside Event document?

Also, `"user": 'Lakshay'` inside `"attendees"` is just a string. Is it advisable to use `reference` data type of Firebase?

Comment: I answered below, but please limit yourself to one question per post in the future.

Comment: I ll keep this in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every user is a different document. Am I doing it correctly?

Yes, this is quite common. Initially it may seem a bit weird to have documents with so little data, but over time you'll get used to it (and likely add more data to each user).

> I have kept Mobile number of every user as Document Id instead of auto id, as the mobile number is going to be unique and it will help me in querying. Is this right?

If the number is unique for each user in the context of your app, then it **can** be used to identify users, and thus also as the ID of the user profile documents. It is slightly more idiomatic to use the user's UID for this purpose, since that is the most common way to look up a user. But if you use phone numbers for that **and** they are unique for each user, you can also use that.

> Here, I have kept attendees as a Map inside the Event document. Is it right or should I make Attendees as a collection inside Event document?

That depends...

- Storing the events for a user in a single document means you have a limit to how many events you can store for a user, as a document can be no bigger than 1MB.
- Storing the events for a user in their document means you always read the data for a user's events, even when you maybe only need to have the user's name. So you'll be reading more data than needed, wasting bandwidth for both you and your users.
- Storing the events inside a subcollection allows you to query them, and read a subset of the events of a user.
- On the other hand: using a subcollection means you end up reading more smaller documents. So you'd be paying for more document reads from a subcollection, while paying less for bandwidth.

> Also, "user": 'Lakshay' inside "attendees" is just a string. Is it advisable to use reference data type of Firebase?

This makes fairly little difference, as there's not a lot of extra functionality that Firestore's `DocumentReference` field type gives.

Comment: Minor upgrade:  because the documentID's are part of Firebase's "sharding" for performance, it is performantly best to make them as *random* as possible so large queries don't access "all adjacent" data.  Phone numbers. even mobile ones, tend to have far less "entropy", reducing efficiency.

For that reason, I would just let user documents be autoID, and store the phone number in a document field.  In addition, you can then query on the document field; it is not always trivial to query on a document ID.

Costs you virtually nothing, and greatly improves performance.